# TFS and SQL Analysis Services Error when processing cubes

Tags: sql, tfs, ssas

I have an issue with TFS at this time. We have TFS and SSAS running on the same machine. A couple of days ago, TFS reporting was working fine but all of a sudden the reports broke and for some reason the TFS Analysis cube cannot be reprocessed. When looking at the processing status, I get the following error:

> Last run result message: [Full Analysis Database Sync]:  ---> AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full, needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: Failed to Process Analysis Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
>   OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not supported on the client.; 08001.

I tried reprocessing the cube, rebuilding both the TFS_Analysis and TFS_Warehouse (from both TFS admin console and command line), and creating new databases; none of these seem to work. Does anyone know the cause of this issue and how to fix it?

TFS is running under under `domain1\tfsserver` account while all of sql is running under a `domain2\tfsserver` account. I believe this might be part of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find one workaround of very similar problem in this blog post: [Fixing Cube Processing ODBC Errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2011/05/27/fixing-cube-processing-odbc-errors.aspx)

Interesting part:

> The Solution
>
> Here is what I did:
>
> Change the service account for Analysis Services from a domain account
> to Local System. Restart SSAS After that, everything started to work
> just fine.
>
> I then set the service account back to the domain account,
> using the updated password, and everything is continuing to run
> correctly. What I didn’t try, and what may work just fine, is to
> simply restart the Analysis Services service.

Comment: Thank you. I changed both the SSAS to use local system and for the SSAS to use "default" authentication followed by restarting the service. The cube is now able to process. Thanks!

Comment: Yep I had the same issues and all I had to do was to restart Analysis Services